# Ternary returns/assignments vs traditional if-else blocks

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) discourages the usage of compound statements, but I couldn't find anything about the advised usage of Python's ternary/conditional syntax. For example:

```
return x if n == 0 else y
i = x if n == 0 else y if n == 1 else z
```

Does there exist any convention concerning whether the above statements should be preferred to more traditional if/else blocks?

```
if n == 0:
    return x
return y

if n == 0:
    i = x
elif n == 1:
    i = y
else:
    i = z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "traditional if/else blocks" should generally be preferred.

The only places where you'd still want to use the ternary operator is in places where the syntax requires an *expression*, e.g. within lambda expressions. Even there, only do it if the ternary expression is short and readable (of course, readability is subjective..)

You can always replace a lambda expression with a small function, but in places where you think that would make the code less readable, it is ok to use lambda expressions with short ternary operations.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with shx2's comments.

Another consideration is testability... using the ternary expr places all the logic on a single line/expr. Basic line-base code coverage tools wouldn't then give a good read on the true coverage of your tests.

Using traditional is/else blocks gives a better reading.